# How to toggle automatic tabbing in visual studio - C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, whitespace, spacing

Is it possible to toggle lines tabulating in C# code (in Visual Studio 2012) to automatic, just like for C++?

For example, if you are working with C++ solution, and you have code like this:

```
if
{
something;

if
somethingelse;
}
```

and you click TAB key, on the beginning or the end of the code, it automaticly changes the whitespace on the beginning of the line to proper, so, in this case if you click once in all of those lines you will get this (depending on number of spaces set in options):

```
if
{
    something;

    if
        somethingelse;
}
```

And you will be able to click tab again and again... and it won't change, unless there is no any wrong whitespace in the line.

But, in C#, it's not working in the same way, which makes me a little angry, because my workflow is now as fast as in C++.

If I click 'tab' once at every single line (at the beginning), it will give me this:

```
    if
    {
    something;

    if
    somethingelse;
    }
```

If I click at the end of the line it will just add spaces there.
If I click more than once I will just get MORE spaces...

```
    if
    {
                    something;

    if
    somethingelse;
    }
```

In C++ it would just make it 'perfect' automagicly.

I can't find it in options. Google is not helping too.
Hope for your help, guys. ;)

Comment: AFAIK VS2012 does it automatically as you type you can view that in the formatting options, you can also press the shortcut to select all lines and then copy and paste and it does automatically reformat everything as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that it's not possible (at least by 'normal' app settings).
I've searched for shortcuts (due to Prix comment) and found those default two:

**Edit.FormatDocument
Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D**

**Edit.FormatSelection
Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F**

The second one is perfect (the first one can change "more" than you want :P).
A little more work but it works as I'd like to.

I hope that this question and answer helped not only me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

the shortcut ctrl+k+d does the trick. [here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Visual-Studio_2010.html) is a list of vs-shortcuts

Comment: Avoid link-only answers, because if the link dies, so does your answer.